# Flutter : Can't get array json using dio to list of object

Tags: flutter, bloc, dio

I tried to load array json (array with no key) and fetch into list of object, here is my sample code :

My ApiCliet :

```
Future<List<OnBoardingModel>> fetchOnboarding() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get("api/OnboardingItem");
      return OnBoardingModel.fromJson(response.data) as List;
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      throw Exception("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
  }
```

My Object (generated using [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/)) :

```
List<OnBoardingModel> onBoardingModelFromJson(String str) => List<OnBoardingModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => OnBoardingModel.fromJson(x)));

String onBoardingModelToJson(List<OnBoardingModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class OnBoardingModel {
  OnBoardingModel({
    this.id,
    this.judul,
    this.deskripsi,
    this.urlGambar,
  });

  int id;
  String judul;
  String deskripsi;
  String urlGambar;

  factory OnBoardingModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => OnBoardingModel(
    id: json["id"],
    judul: json["judul"],
    deskripsi: json["deskripsi"],
    urlGambar: json["urlGambar"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "judul": judul,
    "deskripsi": deskripsi,
    "urlGambar": urlGambar,
  };
}
```

In the end i got an error shown : `Exception: Exception occured: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' stackTrace: #0`, refer to this line `return OnBoardingModel.fromJson(response.data) as List;`

Could you please help me to solve this case. I thank you

**Update**

My json format :

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "judul": "string",
    "deskripsi": "string",
    "urlGambar": "string"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Finally i got the answer, just replace the return using this :

```
return (response.data as List)
          .map((x) => OnBoardingModel.fromJson(x))
          .toList();
```

Complete code :

```
Future<List<OnBoardingModel>> fetchOnboarding() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get("api/OnboardingItem");
      // if there is a key before array, use this : return (response.data['data'] as List).map((child)=> Children.fromJson(child)).toList();
      return (response.data as List)
          .map((x) => OnBoardingModel.fromJson(x))
          .toList();
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      throw Exception("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
  }
```

Hope this answer helps other guests who new in flutter.

Comment: Suprb, Working perfect

Comment: @BaliCode will you please help me . I am stuck in a problem of listing data in flutter .

Comment: @jaspreetSingh  will please help me . I am stuck in a problem of listing data in flutter.

Comment: I am getting the json response  correctely but unable to list them.

Comment: @RahulKushwara : is there any error message appears?

Comment: @RahulKushwaha Can u please show me your code and what response you're trying to parse? Thanks

Comment: @Rahul : check the last paragraph of my question, i have attached the json that i tried to parse

Comment: @BaliCodes My Json Format is like :{
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 8960,
-"articles": [
-{
-"source": {
"id": null,
"name": "Moneycontrol"
},
"author": null,
"title": "String",
"description": "String",
"url": "String",
"urlToImage": "String",
"publishedAt": "sTRING",
"content": "String"
},]}

Comment: @jaspreetSingh I am using NewsApi.org  json api. to get the results and show in list view ...using Dio . I am getting  fine using http but fails to get using dio.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha can u please try with this code see below - 

  return (response.data["articles"] as List)
  .map((x) => NewsResult.fromJson(x)).toList();    

NewsResult is your model here.

Answer (score 1):

import 'dart:convert';

```
List<Welcome> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        this.id,
        this.judul,
        this.deskripsi,
        this.urlGambar,
    });

    int id;
    String judul;
    String deskripsi;
    String urlGambar;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        id: json["id"],
        judul: json["judul"],
        deskripsi: json["deskripsi"],
        urlGambar: json["urlGambar"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "judul": judul,
        "deskripsi": deskripsi,
        "urlGambar": urlGambar,
    };
}
```

**final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);**

Comment: If not test your JSON output properly

Comment: Still face this issue, sir. `Exception: Exception occured: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' stackTrace: #0`

Comment: Can you more details like API you are hiting